# Does Ubuntu 13.04 conclusively support TRIM?

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, intel, ssd, trim

I'm getting ready to install (dual boot) Ubuntu, but I have heard conflicting information on how well supported TRIM is. I'm solely using an Intel 330 and would not install it if I don't know whether it's going to be doing tons of write cycles. Helpful links would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trim is supported, it is not enabled by default
here is a good guide
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd